# filtering multiple criteria with checkbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet called Result, I have created an userform with Listbox.

I would like to filter and see the result for the particular Location. I have totaly 7 Location. If i click more than one Location also, I should be able to see the result.

For this, I created an Listbox with Checkbox, and tried a code like below,

```
Private Sub Filter1()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim strCriteria() As String
Dim arrIdx As Integer

Dim cBox As Control

arrIdx = 0
For Each cBox In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(cBox) = "Listbox" Then
        If cBox.Value = True Then
            ReDim Preserve strCriteria(0 To arrIdx)
            strCriteria(arrIdx) = cBox.Caption
            arrIdx = arrIdx + 1
        End If
    End If
Next cBox

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result")
If arrIdx = 0 Then
    Ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter
Else
    Ws.Range("A:R").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Array(strCriteria), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End If

End Sub
```

I called this filter function in my listbox_change. I dont find any filter function Happening. Could anyone help , where I am wrong and what Need to be modified-

[image: I have an useform like this, when i click on both the Location, I should be able to see the result. If i click on any one also I should b able to see the filter in my sheet accordingly. I used Listbox1.additem to add the Location in my listbox.]

Answer (score 0):

the *strCriteria* is already an array

try `Ws.Range("A:R").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=strCriteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues`